# Why is sympy.plot showing graph as ASCII?

Tags: python, function, plot, graph, sympy

I want to draw a simple graph but sympy is drawing it as ASCII text.
How can I show as an image (with lines)?

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfKwD.png)

Tried different versions of python. Didn't change anything.

Comment: And what's wrong with ASCII charts? Compatible with everything all the way down to an ASR 33.

Comment: Have you installed matplotlib?

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask